# Could IESLight casts shadows in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

From WWDC2016 `Advance SceneKit Rendering` Guide I found that SCNLight have a new type of light -- **IESLight**. *But I found that it couldn't cast shadows*. 
[image]

left is IESLight, right is SpotLight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the ies profile: if it describes a 360° falloff then it is consider as an Omni light and it won t cast shadow. If the angle is < 180° then It will be considered as a spot and it will cast shadow.

Comment: Really? But the doc say IESLight doesn't support cast shadow! Do you have a try?

Comment: Oh it work! Interesting. I am thinking why I didn't get the effect this morning. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I dismiss one point! The doc say that

> Geometries illuminated by the light cast shadows **only if** the value of this property is YES and the type property of the light is **SCNLightTypeSpot or SCNLightTypeDirectional**. The default value is NO.

So I think why IESLight could not cast shadows. Thanks for reading.